# Javascript function inlining

Tags: javascript, performance, inlining

I have the following function, which copies 3 elements from one array-like object to another:

```
function copy(a, b) { 
    a[0] = b[0];
    a[1] = b[1];
    a[2] = b[2];
    return a;
}
```

This function gets called tens of thousands of timed per frame.

Almost all of the calls to it come from a single place in my code.

If I inline it manually in that single location, such that the sets are done directly in the caller, my code becomes significantly faster, meaning the engine isn't inlining it.

Is there some way to make sure JS engines inline it? This is clearly a hot function.
Are there any weird annotations, or vice-versa some code pattern that doesn't allow the engine to inline functions?

I have many similar functions, to work with vectors and matrices, so it would be very cumbersome and ugly to start manually inlining all over the place.

Comment: why a return by giving a reference to an array?

Comment: If you mean why `a` is returned, that's beyond my control (part of external library code).

Comment: what keeps you from a=b ?

Comment: The ECMAScript specification does not dictate how implementations must optimize. It is up to each implementation to determine that. It's entirely possible that one implementation may inline things that others don't.

Comment: @Jonasw beucase I need to copy values, not references.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I realize that, but I wonder if there are any ways to help engines (aka V8 and SpiderMonkey).

Comment: @user2503048 okay. but could you give a bit more coding context, there may be a much easier solution...

Comment: @Jonasw I use many vector functions from the very known glMatrix library to update thousands of 3D skeletal animations running at the same time, but I am not sure how this information can help you :)

Comment: @user2503048 im just thinking of other possibilities, array.slice() for example, im not shure if this is faster, but it might be worth testing. I think you cant rely on browser inlining, so native methods might beat your code...

Comment: @Jonasw Allocations are a big no-no for performance. I worked hard to remove more or less all of the heap allocations (new) from my update loop. Adding an array.slice will work against this. In the end I just manually inlined the simpler calls in my hottest 2 functions (millions of calls per second), and saw a significant improvement in speed